# Why does redirectUrl include hash after redirect?

Tags: auth0

I am using auth0 to do my authentication. My application is a react SPA.

The following code handles authentication within my app.

```
import Auth0Lock from 'auth0-lock';
import {
  receiveLogin,
  receiveProfile
} from '../actions/auth.actions';

export default class AuthService {
  constructor(clientId, domain, dispatch) {
    // Configure Auth0
    this.dispatch = dispatch;
    this.lock = new Auth0Lock(clientId, domain, {
      auth: {
        redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/home',
        responseType: 'token'
      }
    });

    this.lock.on('authenticated', this._doAuthentication.bind(this));
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  }

  login() {
    this.lock.show();
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
  }

  _doAuthentication({ idToken }) {
    this.lock.getProfile(idToken, (error, profile) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Error loading the Profile', error);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', idToken);
        this.dispatch(receiveLogin());
        this.dispatch(receiveProfile(profile));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

After I authenticate, my url in my address bar is

http://localhost:3000/home#

My question is why is there a hash after home and how can I get rid of the hash?

I have not managed to find anything that can tell me how to fix this on the auth0 documentation.

Comment: are you using react-router plus hashHistory?

Comment: I am using `import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';`